# 2.8V UART to 3.3V and 5V MCU automatically

Tags: integrated-circuit, uart, communication, digital-communications, logic-level

I'm designing a PCB of SIM800C Module. Just to improve myself and it is my first project so I'm a noob sorry..

I want GSM module to communicate(from RX,TX pins) with STM32, Raspberry, Arduino. But the problem is their logic levels are different. For example GSM Module logic 1 is 2.8V but other MCU's 3.3V(Raspberry,STM) and 5V(Arduino). So, I need an Integrated Circuit which perceives the logic levels in both side and adjust the levels (amplify or vice versa).

So what I have to do? What should I look at?

Thank you so much!

Comment: You are looking for a "level shifter".

Comment: You can use transistor as a switch to translate 2V8 to 3V3 and 5V. To do the opposite a voltage divider would be enough.

Comment: Can you post the electrical spec, Vin, Vout, Iin, Iout, and etc.?

Comment: you can find it here in this link @jay https://www.hizliresim.com/k4rghki

Comment: Use a level translator or level shifter. Also there are *some* kind of logic tolerant to higher levels (like the LVC that can handle 5V signal when supplied at 3.3V)